# javascript error in ssrs report in axapta 2009

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, axapta

We are using Dynamics Ax 2009 in our company and SSRS 2012 services for reporting.

After installation windows updates on server with Axapta, we faced with problem of viewing ssrs report by users: SSRS reports return javascript error "`Document` is undefined" in any report in filter form when user tryes to choose any value in dropdownlist.

How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by that way:

- Open the reportviewer.aspx file located in \Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages in notepad.
- Change the meta tag from `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">` to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`